# Is any time restrictions to approve websites on google webmasters?

Tags: google-search, google-search-console

**Step 1**

I have added my site to webmasters tools.

**Step 2**

And verified ownership with 
1) uploading the file given by webmasters tool on my server
2) added a meta tag given by webmasters tool in my header file

I Just want to Know that

How many Days will it take to appear my site on Google Search console?

or am I need to do any other steps to verify my sites?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about SEO, not programming. SEO questions may be asked on [Webmasters.SE](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try putting some content into your site. It will take some time/days to index the page on google.

Comment: Try not encouraging off topic questions by answering them.